# Capturar grupos en expresión regular condicionados por los siguientes caracteres

Tags: java, regex

Estoy agrupando registros (tareas) que tienen un código identificador.

El código es único, pero hay tareas que son continuación de otras y eso se refleja en su código. Por ejemplo:

- 12345: Registro original
- 12345A: Nueva versión del registro 12345
- 12345B: Otra version del registro 12345
- 12345C: Tercera versión del registro 12345

Y aquí viene mi problema:

- 12345CONT: Continuación (de la versión activa) del 12345 (da igual si la activa es la original o la A, B o C)
- 12345CONT2: Segunda continuación del 12345
- 12345PF: Información final
- ... (otras terminaciones, siempre de más de una letra

Quiero capturar los siguientes grupos:

```
ID - Versión (A,B,C,D -opcional-) - Tipo de tarea (CONT<n>, PF<n>, ...)
```

Mi regex actualmente es la siguiente:

```
(\d+)[ABCD]?(CONT\d?|PF\d?|REV|REP)?
```

Pero tiene el problema de que `12345CONT` me captura `12345 - C` y me descarta el `ONT`. Estoy mirando opciones "look-ahead", pero no termino de encontrar la solución.

¿Cómo capturar CONT y C por separado?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes usar ['negative lookahead'](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(\d+)(A|B|C(?!ONT)|D)?(CONT\d?|PF\d?|REV|REP)?
```

`C(?!ONT)` capturará `C` solo cuando no es seguido por `ONT`.

([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ix4IYT/1))

Comment: Yo había llegado a esto `(\d+)(CONT\d?|PF\d?|REV|REP)?|([ABCD](?!O))`, pero creo que me gusta mas tu respuesta :)